# Plateletpheresis for hemophilia

Tags: pathology, human-genetics, hematology

Plateletpheresis is seperation of platelets from whole blood and putting the leukocytes and erythrocytes back into the blood.

If the person donating platelets does not have hemophilia than could a hemophilia patient get a periodic transfusion of platelets from a non-hemophiliac platelet donor so that his hemophilia is less severe whether it is hemophilia A or hemophilia B?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [nice page on clotting disorders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemophilia)  - it shows Hemophilia isn't a defect/deficiency of platelets, but rather due to defective clotting factors in the plasma.  When platelets are transfused, they have a very short half-life and are used for acute support in  disorders like [Bernard-Soulier syndrome](http://www.hemophilia.ca/en/bleeding-disorders/platelet-function-disorders/treatment-of-platelet-function-disorders/)

Comment: but platelets are transfused along with plasma aren't they since platelets and plasma are hard to separate? If so than if someone gets a plasma transfusion with platelets which still qualifies as plateletpheresis from someone without hemophilia and the person getting the transfusion has hemophilia it should lower the bleeding from something as simple as bumping on something.

Comment: Indeed, under US standards, an apheresis platelet product contains platelets in _donor plasma_.   But hemophilliacs are typically treated using plasma-derived or manufactured ("recombinant") [clotting factors](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/clotting-factor-replacement-for-hemophilia) since that addresses the actual underlying basis of their condition.

Comment: yes I know but clotting factors are in the plasma so wouldn't it make sense that a non-hemophiliac donor of plasma if it donates blood to a hemophiliac that the clotting factors within the donor plasma would lower the risk of bleeding for much longer than those manufactured clotting factors?

Comment: Plasma contains antibodies that can cause transfusion reactions, so giving bulk  plasma requires cross-matching.  Instead, the _fraction of the plasma enriched in the clotting factor_ needed to complement the deficiency in hemophilia, or recombinant factor is used.   Re duration of effect, in plasma _the factor_ is at x1 concentration.  A plasma fraction could be x1,000 and recombinant x100,000. In the 80s hemophiliacs in Canada got HIV from plasma fractions.  Since it contains no pathogens, recombinant therapy is best.